# Python/Excel - TypeError: 'sheet' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import*emphasized text* open_workbook
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('H:/0python/test.xls')
dataset = workbook.sheet_by_index(0) #取第一张工作簿
labels=['s','c','b','e','o']
myTree=createTree(dataset,labels,data_full,labels_full)
createPlot(myTree)
```

> TypeError: 'Sheet' object is not iterable

I constructed a decision tree before. When I test my data, a problem comes out like this. I don't know why. Who can help me?

Here is the complete code.

## 主程序，递归产生决策树

```
def createTree(dataSet,labels,data_full,labels_full):
    classList=[example[-1] for example in dataSet]
    if classList.count(classList[0])==len(classList):
        return classList[0]
    if len(dataSet[0])==1:
        return majorityCnt(classList)
    bestFeat=chooseBestFeatureToSplit(dataSet,labels)
    bestFeatLabel=labels[bestFeat]
    myTree={bestFeatLabel:{}}
    featValues=[example[bestFeat] for example in dataSet]
    uniqueVals=set(featValues)
    if type(dataSet[0][bestFeat]).__name__=='str':
        currentlabel=labels_full.index(labels[bestFeat])
        featValuesFull=[example[currentlabel] for example in data_full]
        uniqueValsFull=set(featValuesFull)
    del(labels[bestFeat])
    #针对bestFeat的每个取值，划分出一个子树。
    for value in uniqueVals:
        subLabels=labels[:]
        if type(dataSet[0][bestFeat]).__name__=='str':
            uniqueValsFull.remove(value)
        myTree[bestFeatLabel][value]=createTree(splitDataSet\
         (dataSet,bestFeat,value),subLabels,data_full,labels_full)
    if type(dataSet[0][bestFeat]).__name__=='str':
        for value in uniqueValsFull:
            myTree[bestFeatLabel][value]=majorityCnt(classList)
    return myTree
```

Comment: Are you trying to loop over `dataset` somewhere? Maybe in the `createTree` function?

Comment: Yea, I have a long code, can I send you to see it for me? actually, I dont know where is wrong

Comment: Can you update the question?

Comment: how to update it? write them here?

Comment: You can edit your original question to add more code.

Comment: sorry, I dont know how to update. codes are too long to write here

Comment: OK , I try it, Thank you!

Comment: sorry, I have been editting for a long time

Answer (score 0):

> `classList=[example[-1] for example in dataSet]`

in this line, you are trying to loop over `dataSet` but `dataSet` is a sheet, which you can't iterate over.

Comment: fr=open('H:/0python/test.txt')
dataset=[inst.strip().split('\t') for inst in fr.readlines()]
labels=['s','c','b','e','o']
myTree=createTree(dataset,labels,data_full,labels_full)
createPlot(myTree)

Comment: it is also wrong, sorry, I am not familiar with this platform.